# select mulitple class in one parent the short way

Tags: html, css

I have this sample situation

```
<div class="main-class"></div>
```

in the css

```
.main-class {
    maring-top:1px
}
```

so sometimes in my div I add at run time some other class so it could be

```
<div class="main-class a"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="main-class b"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="main-class c"></div>
```

so in my css

```
.main-class.c{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.main-class.a{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.main-class.b{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

or simply

```
.main-class.c,
.main-class.a,
.main-class.b{
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
```

**this is too long**, is there any other ways to do this
**if .main-class has any other (a , b , c) so the margin will be 5px?**

I tried this

```
.main-class:has(.a, .b, .c)
{
margin-top :5xp;
}
```

and this does not work

Comment: Does you `class-a`, `class-b`, and `class-c` start with the same text ("class-") or is it just for the example ?

Comment: ^ And if they don't, could they be changed to add a prefix?

Comment: no my class-a, b and c dont have the same name they are commerce garde and accueil actualy and I can't change them because i'm using theme else where ( like a theme name let's say)

Comment: Please take more care to proofread your questions before posting. Your question contains several errors which make it harder to grab and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes to start with:

- There is no CSS property called `maring-top`.

```css
.main-class.c {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.main-class.a {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.main-class.b {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

can be simplified to

```css
.main-class.c,
.main-class.a,
.main-class.b {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

and even further to

```css
.main-class:is(.c, .a, .b) {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: sorry for the miss speling sure
and Yes i know to select classes in same parent we dont use the (white space)
for the long format I know it, and the question is about it, I want to avoid the long format
and thank you I just tested the is it work
I think it was the has
thank you again

Comment: Please edit your question and correct those mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [connexo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744304/connexo)'s answer, [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/) enables you to write your code like below :

```
.main-class {
    margin-top:1px;
    &.a, 
    &.b, 
    &.c{
        background-color:orange;
    }
}
```

```
<div class="main-class a">A</div>
<div class="main-class b">B</div>
<div class="main-class c">C</div>
<div class="main-class d">D</div>
```

([Codepen](https://codepen.io/cedricbeausseron/pen/KKepmLJ))

Comment: `:is(selectors)` is so much more concise. SASS and any other preprocessors for me is a thing of the past.

Comment: @connexo `:is` is a good solution but I disagree with your opinion about preprocessors, I think it's still usefull to code with a visible and understandable arborescence. I like vanilla CSS but since the goal here is to simplify the code, I just want to highlight this solution too.

Comment: Fair enough. Just pointing out CSS preprocessors will die the same slow death that libraries like jQuery and underscore / lodash do. They've done an amazing job in the past, but mostly aren't really needed any more. See [Native CSS nesting: What you need to know](https://blog.logrocket.com/native-css-nesting/)